# Does karabiner elements on Mac OSX contain, or potentially contain, malware?

Tags: malware, macos, keyloggers, software, opensource

I'm using [Karabiner elements, an open-source program](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements) to remap the keys on my MacBook Air (running the latest Mac OSX High Sierra) and my apple wireless keyboard. It works very nicely.

However, I am concerned about the off chance that a malicious adversary can possibly use it to record keystrokes and passwords. This question was already [asked on a Google Groups thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/osx-karabiner/FJlpy8YEX74), and the creator of Karabiner answered. While there doesn't appear to be any reason to suspect that the creator of the program has anything other than good intentions, I would feel a lot more comfortable with a more independent assessment of this question.

Some further info: the [Github page for the project](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements) has a decent number of contributors, and [the creator of the program](https://pqrs.org/) appears to be someone who I have no reason so far to suspect. However, I'm not as experienced in the world of open-source software development as some others here may be, so I was hoping someone with a better background can shed some light on this issue.

Comment: did you read the source code, it is open source after all?

Comment: I found a mechanical keyboard company, WASD Keyboards, recommending it [on their website](https://www.wasdkeyboards.com/mechanical-keyboard-guide#remap). Of course, that doesn't mean _they_ looked into it, either.

Comment: There is a long discussion between a user and the author on the topic and a potential security risk here: https://github.com/pqrs-org/Karabiner-Elements/issues/1684

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not sure anyone here would be willing to read through it but my advice would be:

1. Read through the bug reports
2. Research information on it and read as many reviews as you can. It has a lot of eyes on it, but it is easy to be sceptical.
3. You could always sandbox it and monitor it, but that's still not a sure way

Long story short, unless you read the code yourself or find someone reviewing the code, you will just have to go with your gut. It has a fair amount of popularity.

Not a lot of people read the source code of something open source. Because it' s open source, they automatically trust it. So it is good you are sceptical. 'Open source' does not mean 'safe', as you seem to be aware.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the source code doesn't necessarily match the distributed binary that users install.